# React-Native app with cocoapods

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react-native application which comes with .xcodeproj file for ios.
I upgraded the project to use cocoapods which added .xcworkspace and updated .xcodeproj file.

Now anytime i try to upgrade react-native to latest version upgrading .xcodeproj is a nightmare.

Just curious if you are facing similar issues then what is the best practice you found to deal with upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had a lot of pain following the recommended ways. Finally, here's what I found to be a pain free way to do the upgrade:

- $ rm package-lock.json (or npm-shrinkwrap.json, whichever you have)
- Update package.json with the new version of React and React-Native dependencies
- $ npm install
- $ npm-shrinkwrap (if you had an npm-shrinkwrap.json)
- $ rm Podfile.lock
- $ pod install

Open workspace (*.xcworkspace) and build.

(This has worked fine when upgrading from 0.46.0 to 0.50.3 version for me)